# Problem with SQL Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am working on a project which uses Java,Spring and Hibernate.
I just came across a situaition like this.

bean 1 :

```
<bean id="cat" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <list>
            <value>cat</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <ref bean="attributeSource"/>
    </property>                          
</bean>
```

bean 2:

```
<bean id="dog" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <list>
            <value>dog</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <ref bean="attributeSource"/>
    </property>                          
</bean>
```

but while executing a getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes 
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data;
    nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection;
    nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been created in this tx context for pool  Illegal attempt to create connection from another pool
Caused by: 
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getExistingConnection(Driver.java:613)
```

Assume cat and dog are two differnt interfaces

cant we have two transaction manager opened ??

Answer (score -2):

Although this is about weblogic the answer might match your problem: http://objectmix.com/weblogic/549975-connection-has-already-been-created-tx-context-pool-named.html

And the answer is basically: No you can't

> The problem is that you can't use two connection pools in one
>   transaction. = A solution is to have a separate method in the bean
>   which is used to call profilePool, and have this method set to
>   TRANSACTION-NOTSUPPORTED, so that the read-only work on profile pool
>   takes place outside of the transaction o= n vcheqPool (I think the
>   error message is saying that profilePool is the read-only one - if not
>   swap 'profilePool and vcheqPool around where they appeared earlier)
>
> In order to use connections from two or more databases in one
>   transaction, you will have to do the following:
>
> - Both drivers must be XA compliant
> - You have to use TXDataSources
> - You need a global transaction, either through the container (SessionBean with "Requires") or through UserTransaction
>
> When you meet all of these requirements, you will be able to use
>   connections from more than one DataSource in one transaction.

Comment: Domain of link in answer is dead.